# C++ Is this a cross-referenced error?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "windows.h"
#include "Submenu.h"
using namespace std;




class Mainmenu
{
string Menu[3];
string MenuName1;
string MenuName2;
string MenuName3;
int pointer = 0;

public:
Mainmenu(string m1, string m2, string m3);
void Firstmenu();
};

Mainmenu::Mainmenu(string m1, string m2, string m3)
{
MenuName1 = m1;
MenuName2 = m2;
MenuName3 = m3;
}
void Mainmenu::Firstmenu()
{
string Menu[3] = { MenuName1,MenuName2,MenuName3 };
while (true)
{

    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 15);
    cout << "basemenu\n\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        if (i == pointer)
        {
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 11);
            cout << Menu[i] << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 15);
            cout << Menu[i] << endl;
        }
    }

    while (true)
    {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP) != 0)
        {
            pointer -= 1;
            if (pointer == -1)
            {
                pointer = 2;
            }
            break;
        }
        else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN) != 0)
        {
            pointer += 1;
            if (pointer == 3)
            {
                pointer = 0;
            }
            break;
        }

        else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RETURN) != 0)
        {
            switch (pointer)
            {

            case 0:
            {

                system("cls");
                Submenu1 a("aa", "bb", "exit");
                a.Sub_one();


            }break;

            case 1:
            {

            }
            break;

            case 2:
            {
                exit(1);
            }
            break;


            }

            break;
        }





    }
    Sleep(150);
    system("cls");
}
}
```

\ this is Mainmenu.h header

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "windows.h"
#include "Mainmenu.h" // ERROR C1014

using namespace std;

class Submenu1
{
string Menu[3];
string SubName1;
string SubName2;
string SubName3;
int pointer = 0;
public:
Submenu1(string s1, string s2, string s3);
void Sub_one();
Mainmenu *a;
};

Submenu1::Submenu1(string s1, string s2, string s3)
{
SubName1 = s1;
SubName2 = s2;
SubName3 = s3;
}

void Submenu1::Sub_one()
{
string Menu[3] = { SubName1, SubName2, SubName3 };

while (true)
{



    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 15);
    cout << "submenu 1\n\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        if (i == pointer)
        {
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 11);
            cout << Menu[i] << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 15);
            cout << Menu[i] << endl;
        }
    }




    while (true)
    {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP) != 0)
        {
            pointer -= 1;
            if (pointer == -1)
            {
                pointer = 2;
            }
            break;
        }
        else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN) != 0)
        {
            pointer += 1;
            if (pointer == 3)
            {
                pointer = 0;
            }
            break;
        }




        else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RETURN) != 0)
        {
            switch (pointer)
            {


            case 0:
            {

            }break;

            case 1:

            {/*system("cls");*/
                cout << "\n\nstandard";
                Sleep(1000);
            }break;

            case 2:  
            {
                system("cls");

                Mainmenu a("a", "b", "return");
                a.Firstmenu();
            }break;


            }

            break;
        }





    }
    Sleep(150);
    system("cls");
}

};
```

/ This is Submenu.h header

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "windows.h"
#include "Mainmenu.h"

using namespace std;


int main() 
{
system("mode con:cols=50 lines=30");
Mainmenu test("a", "b", "c");
test.Firstmenu();
return 0;
}
```

/ This is main.cpp

1. On the initial screen of the console window, I created three menus (ex 1, 2, 3).
2. Number 1 to enter the submenu. / (Number 2 Not set) / Number 3 console shut down
3. Press 1 to enter the submenu.

4.For example, the submenu items are 1S, 2S, and 3S.

5. There is an error in this area -> Press 3S to return to the first screen.

   I think it is cross reference error..
   How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Too many files included. Level = 1024      and The # Included file contains its own file itself.

Comment: I think you need to reduce the size of this example (probably by a factor of five or so).  For example, create all the menus with fixed content (rather than passing it in the constructor), and don't bother colouring the text. Also, *start* by describing the problem, then show the code.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It seems difficult, but I'll try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about to add include-guard?

---

> In "Submenu.h" --- case 2: { system("cls"); Mainmenu a("a", "b", "return"); a.Firstmenu(); }break;
>   C2605 'Mainmenu' : Undefined identifier.

include "Mainmenu.h" in "Submenu.h".(Don't forget include guard for all header files)

Comment: Does that mean adding #pragma once?

Comment: Either that, or the traditional (and standard).  `#ifndef FOO_INCLUDED\n#DEFINE FOO_INCLUDED\n<contents of header>#endif\n`

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did your advice, but I got another error.  
C2605 'Mainmenu' : Undefined identifier.

Answer (score 0):

> this is Mainmenu.h header
>
> ```
> #include <iostream>
> #include <string>
> #include "windows.h"
> #include "Mainmenu.h" // ERROR C1014
> ```

Why are you including "Mainmenu.h" inside itself?  That is *at best* pointless, and in this case actively harmfull.

Comment: #include "Mainmenu.h" I erased this line and there was a new error.

Comment: In "Submenu.h"     ---         case 2:  
            {
                system("cls");

                Mainmenu a("a", "b", "return");
                a.Firstmenu();
            }break;

Comment: C2605 'Mainmenu' : Undefined identifier.